# How is setting default=1 for foreignkey supposed to work?

Tags: django

I have a model `Order`,

```
class Order(SmartModel):
    #each individual status
    SUBMITTED = 1 # the credit card was valid or mobilemoney was recieved.It is ready for us to process the order
    PROCESSED = 2 # After submitted orders are reviewed, we can mark them as processed, letting deliverers know order is ready to be shipped
    DELIVERED = 3 # the order has been processed and approved by the adminstrator(in this case us), it is delivered.
    PICKED_UP =4 # the order has been processed and is picked up by customer
    CANCELLED = 5 # Customer called the company and decided they didnt want to go through with the order either by phone or email.

    # SET OF POSSIBLE STATUSES
    ORDER_STATUSES = ((SUBMITTED,'Submitted'),(PROCESSED,'Processed'),(DELIVERED,'Delivered'),(PICKED_UP,'picked_up'),(CANCELLED,'Cancelled'),)
    #Order info
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=ORDER_STATUSES, default=SUBMITTED)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer,help_text="The customer who made this order",default=1)
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant,default = '1',help_text="The restaurant the customer order from")
```

as you can see i have set `customer a foreignkey` default to `1`. here is the `Customer` model

```
    class Customer(SmartModel):
        #contact info
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=50,help_text="Needed as alternative")
        mobile = PhoneNumberField(max_length=20,default='+25078######',help_text="Needed to communicate and confirm payment from mobile money")

        #billing information
        billing_name= models.CharField(max_length=50,help_text="Needed so we can deliver to the right individual")
        billing_address= models.CharField(max_length=50,help_text="Needed for delivery purposes, should be office address.")    
        billing_city = models.CharField(ma

x_length=50,help_text="F4L services are only in selected cities.")


    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s %s %s %s" % (self.email,self.mobile,self.billing_name,self.billing_address,self.billing_city)
```

here is how i validate the form.

```
def show_checkout(request):
    if order.is_empty(request):
        cart_url = urlresolvers.reverse('order_index')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(cart_url)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        postdata = request.POST.copy()
        form = forms.CheckoutForm(request.POST,postdata)
        if form.is_valid():
            anon_user = User.objects.get(id=settings.ANONYMOUS_USER_ID)
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.created_by = anon_user
            obj.modified_by = anon_user
            obj.save()
            if postdata['submit'] == 'place order':
                reciept_url = urlresolvers.reverse('checkout_reciept')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reciept_url)
    else:
        form = forms.CheckoutForm
    context = {
        'form':form,
    }
    return render_to_response('checkout/checkout.html',context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

in this function i go ahead to create customer and add it to customer,

```
def add_to_order(request,obj):  
    postdata = request.POST.copy()
    #get quantity added, return 0 if empty
    quantity = postdata.get('quantity',0)
    # fetch the item or return  missing page error_message
    i = get_object_or_404(Item,pk=obj.id)
#   order = get_object_or_404(Order,pk=obj.id)
    # get items in order
    order_items = get_order_items(request)
    item_in_orders = False
    # check to see if item is already in order
    for order_item in order_items:
        if order_item.item.id == i.id:
            #update the quantity if found
            order_item.augment_quantity(quantity)
            item_in_orders = True
    if not item_in_orders:
        # creat and save a new order item
        anon_user = User.objects.get(id=settings.ANONYMOUS_USER_ID)
        try:
#           customer = Customer.objects.get(pk=customer_id)
            order= Order.objects.get(pk=order_id)
#           restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(pk=restaurant_id)
        except:
            customer = Customer.objects.create(created_by=anon_user,modified_by=anon_user)
#           customer.save()
#           import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
#           restaurant = Restaurant(created_by=anon_user,modified_by=anon_user)
#           restaurant.save()
            order = Order.objects.create(customer=customer,created_by=anon_user,modified_by=anon_user)
#           order.save()
#       import pdb;pdb.set_trace()  
        oi=OrderItem.objects.create(order=order,shopping_id=_shopping_id(request),
                                          quantity=quantity,
                                          item=i,
                                          created_by=anon_user,
                                          modified_by=anon_user)
        oi.save()
```

this function is called when am creating a new orderitem

```
def show_item(request,id):
    # need to evaluate the HTTP method
    if request.method == 'POST':
#       import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        a = Item.objects.get(pk=id)
        form = PartialOrderItemForm(request.POST,instance=a)
        # check validation of posted data
        if form.is_valid():
            order.add_to_order(request,a)
            # if test cookie worked, get rid of it
            if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
                request.session.delete_test_cookie()
            url =urlresolvers.reverse('order_index')
            # redirect to order page
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        form = PartialOrderItemForm()
    request.session.set_test_cookie()
    context={
#       'categories':categories,
        'form':form,
#       'menu':menu,

    }
    return render_to_response('item.html',context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The thing is when I submit the customer form in the browser, in my admin the `customer` always returns the same data for each different submission.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I have no idea what you think setting default to 1 is supposed to do, or why you are surprised you always get the same user.

Comment: @DanielRoseman hey man, if you not gon help, how about you keep your opinions to yourself..alright, we all not as good as you are at these things, alright..

Answer (score 0):

`default` just means "hey, if I don't explicitly set a value, use this".

So in your example, `default=1` is telling Django (or more specifically, the database) that, unless you specifically pass or set the value of Order.customer, it should set it to the Customer record which has a primary key of `1`.

I don't see anywhere in your view where you're creating a customer object and setting that into the `Order`.

Comment: hey thanks for the insight,but how do u suggest i should create the `customer` object and set it into the order..what am currently implementing is not working. something like this, `customer = Customer.objects.create(...)` then, `order=Order.objects.create(customer=customer)` ..this is not doing the right thing

Comment: That looks like it should work. Can you update your question with the full source of your view which includes that code?

Comment: You need to save the customer after you call create. Create, on it's own, doesn't create the record. I see you have a line in there to do it, but it's commented out.